# React Native - When clicking on drawer component bottom navigation not showing

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation-drawer, react-native-navigation

I'm new to React Native and building a simple application with a Login, Registration, Home, and Settings screen.

I have installed **Stack Navigator**, **Drawer Navigator** & **Bottom Tabs Navigator** and the issue I'm facing is that when I'm logged in with a user credential I am redirected to the Home screen where I can see the Bottom Tab and Drawer.

Now when click on Settings from the **Drawer**, the Bottom Tab not showing.

Drawer

[image]

Here bottom navigation not showing

[image]

Here is the code:

**App.js**

```
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import React from 'react';
import AuthContext from './src/contexts/AuthContext';
import AuthNavigator from "./src/navigation/AuthNavigator";
import MainNavigator from "./src/navigation/MainNavigator";

export default function App({ navigation }) {
    const Stack = createStackNavigator();

    const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(
        (prevState, action) => {
            switch (action.type) {
                case 'SIGN_IN':
                    return {
                        ...prevState,
                        isSignout: false,
                        userToken: action.token,
                    };
                case 'SIGN_OUT':
                    return {
                        ...prevState,
                        isSignout: true,
                        userToken: null,
                    };
            }
        },
        {
            isLoading: true,
            isSignout: false,
            userToken: null,
        }
    );

    const authContext = React.useMemo(
        () => ({
            signIn: async (data) => {
                dispatch({ type: 'SIGN_IN', token: data });
            },
            signOut: () => dispatch({ type: 'SIGN_OUT' })
        }),
        []
    );

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={authContext}>
            <NavigationContainer>
                {state.userToken == null ? (
                    <AuthNavigator />
                ) : (
                    <MainNavigator />
                )}
            </NavigationContainer>
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    );
}
```

**AuthNavigator**

```
import React from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

import {
    Login,
    Registration,
} from '../screens';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function AuthNavigator() {
    return (
        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Login" screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
            <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Register" component={Registration} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
    );
}

export default AuthNavigator;
```

**MainNavigator**

```
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import React from 'react';

import {
    Settings,
} from '../screens';
import TabNavigator from './TabNavigator';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

function MainNavigator() {
    return (
        <Drawer.Navigator>
            <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={TabNavigator} />
            <Drawer.Screen name="Settings" component={Settings} />
        </Drawer.Navigator>
    );
}

export default MainNavigator;
```

**TabNavigator**

```
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { Icon } from '@rneui/themed';

import {
    Chat,
    Documents,
    Login,
    Properties,
    RecentActivity,
} from '../screens';

const TabNavigator = () => {
    const navigation = useNavigation();
    const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

    return (
        <Tab.Navigator initialRouteName="Properties" screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
            <Tab.Screen name="Properties" component={Properties}
                options={{
                    tabBarIcon: ({ focused, title }) => {
                        const color = focused ? '#84b545' : '#a1a5b8';

                        return (
                            <>
                                <Ionicons
                                    name='home'
                                    type='ionicon'
                                    size={28}
                                    color={color}
                                />
                            </>
                        );
                    }
                }} />
            <Tab.Screen name="Documents" component={Documents} options={{
                tabBarIcon: ({ focused, title }) => {
                    const color = focused ? '#84b545' : '#a1a5b8';

                    return (
                        <>
                            <Ionicons
                                name='documents'
                                type='ionicon'
                                size={28}
                                color={color}
                            />
                        </>
                    );
                }
            }} />
            <Tab.Screen name="RecentActivity" component={RecentActivity}
                options={{
                    tabBarIcon: ({ focused, title }) => {
                        const color = focused ? '#84b545' : '#a1a5b8';

                        return (
                            <>
                                <Ionicons
                                    name='timer'
                                    type='ionicon'
                                    size={28}
                                    color={color}
                                />
                            </>
                        );
                    }
                }} />
            <Tab.Screen name="Chat" component={Chat} options={{
                tabBarIcon: ({ focused, title }) => {
                    const color = focused ? '#84b545' : '#a1a5b8';

                    return (
                        <>
                            <Ionicons
                                name='chatbox-ellipses'
                                type='ionicon'
                                size={28}
                                color={color}
                            />
                        </>
                    );
                }
            }} />
            <Tab.Screen name="Menu" component={Chat}
                options={{
                    tabBarIcon: ({ focused, title }) => {
                        const color = focused ? '#84b545' : '#a1a5b8';

                        return (
                            <>
                                <Ionicons
                                    name='menu'
                                    type='ionicon'
                                    size={28}
                                    color={color}
                                />
                            </>
                        );
                    }
                }} />
        </Tab.Navigator>
    );
};

export default TabNavigator;
```

I have gone through the document but I'm new in React Native so I don't understand that's why I came here to get more guidance on this.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

**Problem**

The reason tabs are not showing in the settings screen is because the settings drawer doesnt point to the tabs navigator. So it only shows you the settings screen as instructed.

**Suggestion**

Instead, if you want the settings screen to also have tabs navigation, you need to put the settings screen under the tabs navigator. Can be its own tab or under a stack which would be under one of the tabs.

**Solution**

To have the settings drawer navigate to the settings tab using the same Tabs navigator; modify the tabs navigator to look like this:

```
const TabNavigator = ({route}) => {
  const {initialRouteName} = route.params; // Passed down a variable from the drawers to decide what screen to render first
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      initialRouteName={initialRouteName} // Dynamically selects initial route based on drawer selected
      screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
      <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={Settings} /> {/*Added Settings Tab*/}
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Properties"
        component={Properties}
        .
        .
        .
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};

export default TabNavigator;
```

After that we need to pass initialRouteName as initialParams when declaring the drawers in the drawer navigator.

```
function MainNavigator() {
  return (
      <Drawer.Navigator>
          <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={TabNavigator}
            initialParams={{initialRouteName: 'Properties'}} />
          <Drawer.Screen name="Settings" component={Settings}
            initialParams={{initialRouteName: 'Settings'}} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
}
```

Note: In the above solution I passed around the **variable** 'initialRouteName'. You can name it anything you like, I chose this name because its easily relatable to the Navigator **prop** 'initialRouteName'